# delegate property is nill while sending data from table cell to a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a problem with the delegation pattern, I'm trying to send data from a table view cell to another view controller like this but when I set the delegate property inside the second controller (the receiver), it is nil, can anyone explain this to me, I am new to this

the protocol and the sender class:

```
import UIKit

protocol SendDataDelegate {
    func updateProperties(_ data: CellData)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
        
    var arr: [CellData] = [
        CellData(img: UIImage(named: "1")!, str1: "welcome1", str2: "hello1"),
        CellData(img: UIImage(named: "2")!, str1: "welcome2", str2: "hello2"),
        CellData(img: UIImage(named: "3")!, str1: "welcome3", str2: "hello3"),
        CellData(img: UIImage(named: "4")!, str1: "welcome4", str2: "hello4"),
        CellData(img: UIImage(named: "5")!, str1: "welcome5", str2: "hello5"),
        CellData(img: UIImage(named: "6")!, str1: "welcome6", str2: "hello6"),
        CellData(img: UIImage(named: "7")!, str1: "welcome7", str2: "hello7"),
        CellData(img: UIImage(named: "8")!, str1: "welcome8", str2: "hello8"),
        CellData(img: UIImage(named: "9")!, str1: "welcome9", str2: "hello9"),
        CellData(img: UIImage(named: "10")!, str1: "welcome10", str2: "hello10")
    ]
    
    var delegate: SendDataDelegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTableView()
    }
        
    fileprivate func setupTableView() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate   = self
        tableView.register(
            UINib(nibName: Constants.cellNibName, bundle: nil),
            forCellReuseIdentifier: Constants.cellIdentifier
        )
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: Constants.cellIdentifier,
            for: indexPath
        ) as! TableCell
        cell.picture.image = arr[indexPath.row].img
        cell.label1.text   = arr[indexPath.row].str1
        cell.label2.text   = arr[indexPath.row].str2
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(300.0)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.storyboardName, bundle: nil)
        let nextController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(
            withIdentifier: Constants.destinationController
        ) as! SecondController
        
        var data = arr[indexPath.row]
        delegate?.updateProperties(data)
        present(nextController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

and here's the receiver class:

```
import UIKit

class SecondController: UIViewController {
        
    @IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView! {
        didSet {
            picture.image = img
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var label11: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            label11.text = s1
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var label22: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            label22.text = s2
        }
    }

    var s1 = ""
    var s2 = ""
    var img = UIImage()
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        
        let controller = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.storyboardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(
        withIdentifier: Constants.firstController
        ) as! ViewController
        controller.delegate = self
        print(s1)
    }
    
}

extension SecondController: SendDataDelegate {
    
    func updateProperties(_ data: CellData) {
        self.s1 = data.str1
        self.s2 = data.str2
        self.img = data.img
    }
    
}
```

Comment: do you set number of section for tableView?

Comment: no i only set the number of rows in section

Comment: try with calling number of section method, without it you can't create cell.'

Comment: I got your isue. You dont need to send data using delegate when you push screen. You can simply use code: nextController.setData(passvalue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figured it out, inside my sender class in this function:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.storyboardName, bundle: nil)
        let nextController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(
            withIdentifier: Constants.destinationController
        ) as! SecondController
        
        var data = arr[indexPath.row]
        delegate?.updateProperties(data)
        present(nextController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

i added this line `delegate = nextController` before passing the data to the updateProperties() functions and that worked

Answer (score 0):

Here there is no need for a delegate you only need to pass the model item

```
nextController.sendedItem = arr[indexPath.row]
```

And inside `SecondController`

```
var sendedItem:CellData?
```

The inside `viewDidLoad` set the values

**Edit:**

```
nextController.updateProperties(data)
present(nextController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I know, but this is a task that's assigned to me and they want me to use delegation pattern

Comment: delegate is used to send data from SeconController to the First one not vice versa , see edit for another possible way with delegate